# Qt not emitting signal

Tags: c++, windows, qt, signals

I am newbie, I am trying to emit signal from a header file and catch it in my main class. for this have written this header file :-

```
KeyBoard.h:-

#ifndef KEYBOARD_H
#define KEYBOARD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class KeyBoard : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    KeyBoard();
    int keyboard_update(QByteArray recieved_key);
signals:
    void keyboard_respoense(QString message);
private:
    int level;
    int sub_level;

};

#endif
```

and

```
KeyBoard.cpp:-

#include "KeyBoard.h"

KeyBoard::KeyBoard()
{
    level = 0;
    sub_level = 0;
}

int KeyBoard::keyboard_update(QByteArray recieved_key)
{
    qDebug() << "recieved key == " << recieved_key;
        qDebug() << "button  == " << recieved_key.at(8);    
    emit keyboard_respoense("PRESS ENTER TO SELECT TRAIN"); 

    return 1;
}
```

In my main class, I am catching my signal like this:-

```
keyboard = new KeyBoard;
connect(keyboard,SIGNAL(keyboard_respoense(QString message)),this,SLOT(send_to_MBU(QString message)));
```

but when I call keyboard_update function using this line:-

```
keyboard->keyboard_update(raw_data_MBU_qb);
```

It enters in keyboard_update() function but never emits the signal, or may be it emits the signal but I am not able to catch it. So, please tell me what exactly I am missing here.

Comment: Please share the code of `send_to_MBU` method.

Comment: Your connection is wrong. It should be `connect(keyboard, SIGNAL(keyboard_respoense(QString)), this, SLOT(send_to_MBU(QString)));` instead, i.e. no need to include parameter names.

Comment: @ vahancho : It's thanks bro. It's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `connect` function, no need to mention parameter names. just declare on argument type. Connect like this:-

```
connect(keyboard,SIGNAL(keyboard_respoense(QString)),this,SLOT(send_to_MBU(QString)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To let compiler help you, please update to C++11 or more modern and write
connect(keyboard, &Keyboard::Keyboard_respoense, this, &SnakeCaseClass:send_to_MBU);